# Change elements in a python pandas dataframe slice with a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

Wondering if anyone can help me with this problem. I am working on a machine learning problem, I have classified the `df1[Age]` column into `df1[Age_group]`. Unfortunately there are missing data, so any `df[Age]` which is `NaN` is classified as `3`.

Currently the classification of `3` only means "missing data", and I want to update this to something useful. I have used scikit-learn logistic regression to *guess* the missing age groups and they are now stored in a Numpy array which I have called `missing_age_grps`.

Obviously the data set I am working with is much bigger, but below should be enough data to illustrate the problem.

In the example below `missing_age_grps` is an array of only 2, due to only 2 instances of `df1[Age_group] == 3`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'Sex': ["Male","Female","Male","Male", "Female"], 'Age':[np.nan, 23, np.nan, 6, 15] , 'Age_group':[3,2,3,0,1]}
df1 = pd.Dataframe(d)

print(df1)

ID   Sex         Age  Age_group
0    Male        NaN      3   
1    Female      23       2   
2    Male        NaN      3
3    Male        6        0
4    Female      15       1 /....

print(missing_age_grps)

[0, 1]
```

I am having trouble re-writing only the values in the `df1['Age_group']` which are represented by `3`.

The ideal solution will update only the 3's with the values from the numpy array. This is the expected output:

```
print(df1)

ID   Sex         Age  Age_group
0    Male        NaN      0   
1    Female      23       2   
2    Male        NaN      1
3    Male        6        0
4    Female      15       1 /....
```

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['Age'].isna(), 'Age_group'] = age_group`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I do not see any `numpy.array` I will just make a value for those value and replace it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'Sex': ["Male","Female","Male","Male", "Female"], 'Age':[np.nan, 23, np.nan, 6, 15] , 'Age_group':[3,2,3,0,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
replacement_array = np.array([22, 23])
df1.loc[df1['Age_group'] ==3, 'Age_group'] = replacement_array
print(df1)
```

The logic is just to replace your `subset of values` in your case `df1['Age_group'] == 3` with your replacement value

Comment: Sorry if this isn't obvious from the question, but the replacement value isn't always 2. It may be 0, 1, or 2. I will update the question to reflect this ...

Comment: so use `replacement_value = [0,1]`

Comment: I adjusted the answer as per your request @hamslice

Comment: Actually I am not able to pass a list into this, I get the following error ```ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable```

Comment: check the updated code, probably you are doing this
`df1.loc[df1['Age_group'] ==3, :] = replacement_array` instead of `df1.loc[df1['Age_group'] ==3, "Age_group"] = replacement_array`